Is it OK to mix Bayesian and frequentist methods in the same paper?
I'm writing a paper for a psychology journal. Initially, I planned to use only frequentist methods for my analyses. However, I found that the nlme package I was using for regression analyses was unable to apply parameter bounds in the way I needed. So I switched to the brms package, which allowed me to set priors on each parameter in the regression analyses, effectively constraining the parameters in the way I was hoping to achieve with nlme.
I’m using frequentist methods for my basic descriptives and some exploratory analyses (i.e., some t-test comparisons, etc), and Bayesian methods for the more complex regression analyses (unrelated to the exploratory analyses). As long as I explain my approach clearly, is this practice acceptable? I'm concerned about whether it's acceptable to mix frequentist and Bayesian methods in the same paper, especially if they are used for different analyses. Would this cause problems for some reviewers?

What do you mean by more accurate tools? What methods of analysis did you use? If you add more detail, people might be able to point you to fully Bayesian (or frequentist) implementations of both types of analyses you conducted. If they perform a similar task (e.g., a regression analysis), writing the discussion correctly using two interpretations  is going to be a pain.

Great point, I've edited the question to be more specific about the types of analyses performed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you've estimated your regression with brms already, what part of your analysis remains that is still distinctively frequentist?

Just the descriptive analyses, along with some exploratory tests that were unrelated to the main regression analyses

Andrew Gelman probably has some cogent writings on this point, but I think that descriptive statistics are neither Bayesian nor frequentist.  Things diverge more when inference is involved.
Having a mixture of types of analyses in a paper is not inherently wrong, but it can be confusing.  Readers have to switch between hard-to-interpret and drastically-differently-interpreted posterior probabilities for one thing.  For $t$-tests I would definitely use a Bayesian $t$-test which includes the right uncertainties for normality and equal variance.  If you want to use a Wilcoxon test use the Bayesian Wilcoxon test (Bayesian proportional odds ordinal logistic regression).  Both of these Bayesian tests are discussed and  exemplified here.

In principle, you would hope that any journal would let you use the best tool for a job for separate questions in a paper. There's of course no rule, theorem or anything else that requires you to strictly stick to one inferential approach (I guess if you are sending something to a regulatory authority like the US FDA, maybe they would request based on discussions with you something like type I error control across multiple analyses, which then might be something you would then try to do consistently). However, my impression is that reviewers often like a consistent approach. Doing simple frequentist summary statistics followed by Bayesian inference is a pretty common consistent approach of what gets used when. Mixing things up more (e.g. some inferential analysis one way other a different way) may lead to questions from reviewers, but when there's a good reason to do it that way, I'd hope it wouldn't be a problem.

Just beware that $\alpha$ is not the probability of making an error, so controlling $\alpha$, though commonly requested, is not noble.  More here.
